# I am facing runtime error while building an android application

Tags: java, android, firebase

My Error message:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.blood_doner, PID: 9696
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.blood_doner/com.example.blood_doner.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.blood_doner:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.blood_doner:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class LinearLayoutCompat
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.blood_doner:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.blood_doner:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class LinearLayoutCompat
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.blood_doner:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class LinearLayoutCompat
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.LinearLayoutCompat
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:813)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:774)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:911)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.blood_doner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.LinearLayoutCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~E_zA6DvG2UIaGgWdJTrtLw==/com.example.blood_doner-WiH1_nFAcKgFOSBhTUwffw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~E_zA6DvG2UIaGgWdJTrtLw==/com.example.blood_doner-WiH1_nFAcKgFOSBhTUwffw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 33 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9696 SIG: 9
```

My activity_Main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_image"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
    
            <include
                layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>
    
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:text="Home"
              android:textSize="50sp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:gravity="center"/>
    
    
    
        </LinearLayoutCompat>
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:background="@drawable/background_image">
    
        </RelativeLayout>
        <include
            layout="@layout/main_nav_drawer"/>
    
    
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/top_layout"
                >
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/helpline_button"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/request_button"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/helpline"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    
                    />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/request_button"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/request"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/organization_button"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
    
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/organization" />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/plasma_button"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
    
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/plasma"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/organization_button"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    
    
            </RelativeLayout>
    
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"
                android:id="@+id/blood_group"
    
                >
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/a_positive_button"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/a_positive" />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/a_negative_button"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/a_positive_button"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/a_negative"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="420dp" />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/b_positive_button"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
    
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/a_negative_button"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/b_positive" />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/b_negative_button"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b_positive_button"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/b_negative"
                    />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ab_positive_button"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/a_positive_button"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ab_positive" />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ab_negative_button"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/a_negative_button"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ab_positive_button"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ab_negative" />
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/o_positive_button"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/a_negative_button"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ab_negative_button"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/o_positive" />
    
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/o_negative_button"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/o_positive_button"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/b_negative_button"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/o_negative" />
    
    
            </RelativeLayout>
    
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/log_out"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:onClick="logout"
                android:text="Log out"
                android:layout_below="@+id/blood_group"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                />
    
    
        </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My main Activity.java

```
package com.example.blood_doner;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Initialize variable
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


    }

    public void ClickMenu(View view){
        //open drawer
        openDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }

    public static void openDrawer(DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        //open drawer layout
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    public void ClickLogo(View view){
        closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }

    public static void closeDrawer(DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        //close drawer layout
        //checks condition
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            //when drawer is open close the drawer
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }

    public void ClickHome(View view){
        //recreate activity
        recreate();

    }

    public void ClickDashboard(View view){
        //redirect activity to dashboard
        redirectActivity(this, Dashboard.class); //Dashboard.class
    }

    public void ClickAboutUs(View view){
        redirectActivity(this, AboutUs.class); //AboutUs.class
    }

    public void ClickLogout(View view){
        Logout(this);
    }
    //temporary
    public static void Logout(Activity activity) {
//        AlertDialog.Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
//        builder.setTitle("Logout");
//        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
//        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
//            @Override
//                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
//                activity.finishAffinity();
                System.exit(0);
//            }
//        });

//        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
//                dialog.dismiss();
//
//            }
//
//        });
//        builder.show();

    }

    public static void redirectActivity(Activity activity, Class aClass) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, aClass);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        closeDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }

    public void logout(View view) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

I didn't understand what's the issue is? I'am new to android development and I don't understand any of the error message. Please help me fix this problem! The application is crashing when I'm trying to run! I have given my code sample and error message on the top!

Comment: This is an inflation exception with LinearLayoutCompat. Class not found. Try a LinearLayout instead!

Comment: Show your build.gradle where you have added dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

with

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
```